# print the line after matching specific string using grep command

Tags: unix, terminal, grep, ubuntu-12.04

I want to print the complete line after matching a string

For example, I have this input:-

```
  www.google.com/images
  www.google.com/images/12
  www.yahoo.com/images/12
  www.bing.com/images/34
  www.google.com/images/12
  www.google.com/images/imagescols
```

And I want this output:-

```
 com/images              
 com/images/12           
 com/images/12           
 com/images/34           
 com/images/12           
 com/images/imagescols
```

please suggest a way to do this using the grep command in unix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the below cut command.

```
cut -d. -f3 file
```

OR

```
awk -F. '{print $NF}' file
```

OR

```
grep -oE '[^.]*$' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ cut -d. -f3 file
com/images
com/images/12
com/images/12
com/images/34
com/images/12
com/images/imagescols
```

Comment: Hi avinash,thanks for your answer.Is there any method by which I can include the dot as well.I  mean:-

.com/images            
.com/images/12         
.com/images/12         
.com/images/34         
.com/images/12         
.com/images/imagescols

Comment: try `awk -F. '{print "."$NF}' file` or `grep -oE '\.[^.]*$' file`